# How does SSLSocket send heart connection like Socket.sendUrgentData()

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I used `Socket.sendUrgentData()` to keep connection alive. But for security, now I attempt to change it to SSLSocket. SSLSocket doesn't inherit this method with exception:

```
SSLSocket not supproted this method.
```

Is there any better way than implement our `own sendUrgentData()`, which means implementing the method of sending heart connection.

My code is like this:

```
public void checkConnection(SSLSocket sslSocket) {
    if(sslSocket == null){
        return;
    }
    try{
        //socket.sendUrgentData(0xFF);
        sslSocket.getOutputStream.write(0xFF);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
public SSLSocket init(){
    /**
     * ip,port,KeyManagerFactory, TrustManagerFactory
     */
    return (SSLSocket)context.getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port);
}
```

Or some suggestions about optimizing `sslSocket.getOutputStream.write(0xFF)`? Thanks.

Comment: how did you create `sslSocket`?

Comment: @Spara By CA, client, server keystore. And I add the method in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, the `SSLSocket` implementations do not support `sendUrgentData`.  This is from the source code for `sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl`:

```
/**
 * Send one byte of urgent data on the socket.
 * @see java.net.Socket#sendUrgentData
 * At this point, there seems to be no specific requirement to support
 * this for an SSLSocket. An implementation can be provided if a need
 * arises in future.
 */
@Override
public final void sendUrgentData(int data) throws SocketException {
    throw new SocketException("This method is not supported "
                    + "by SSLSockets");
}
```

You then ask:

> Or some suggestions about optimizing `sslSocket.getOutputStream.write(0xFF)`

Assuming that you mean "expedite" rather than "optimize", you should call `flush()` on the stream after the `write()`.

But you also need to be a bit careful with this.  If you have wrapped the socket's output stream with a `BufferedOutputStream`, a `Writer` stack, or something similar, then diving down and writing a byte to the underlying stream could mess things up.   Your "heart beat" message (if that is what this is) could appear randomly in the middle of some other message.

Comment: `flush()`,ok. Maybe I have to implement my own "heart beat". Thanks